# Angular 12 HttpClient POST to string does not compile

Tags: angular

I have a `POST` method returning a plain string.

The following does not compile

```
public ping(): Observable<string> {
    return this.httpClient.post<string>(this.uri, {}, {
      observe: 'body', responseType: 'text'
    });
  }
```

Error is

```
TS2322: Type 'Observable<ArrayBuffer>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'.     Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

It looks like Webstorm insists to compile my statement into the following public method of the `HttpClient` (ctrl-clicked on it)

```
post(url: string, body: any | null, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    context?: HttpContext;
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | number | boolean | ReadonlyArray<string | number | boolean>;
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType: 'arraybuffer';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<ArrayBuffer>;
```

How do I correctly tell Angular that the server is returning a plain `string`?

Comment: Can you remove the generic type, it should end up with https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/51610849171c8b02aa63a9cde163dd40f0585854/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L2279-L2297

Comment: If you say to Angular that want received the whole response (you are using {observe: 'body', responseType: 'text'}, you received a whole response, you need "map" the response to only get the body return `this.httpClient.post<string>(...).pipe(map(x=>x.body))`. NOTE: Geenerally you need only say {responseType: 'text'}, see the docs:https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: @Eliseo no, it's `observe: 'response'` that would give the whole response.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, ::glups: true, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the generic type that's confusing things, the following works just fine:

```js
return this.httpClient.post(this.uri, {}, {
  observe: 'body', responseType: 'text'
});
```

If you look in [the implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/12.0.x/packages/common/http/src/client.ts) you can see only three overloads with a generic type argument, `post<T>`, all of which expect `responseType: 'json'`. Given that the compiler can't match *any* of the overloads, it shows you the error from applying the [first one listed](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/12.0.x/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L2223-L2241) for the method, which indeed returns `Observable<ArrayBuffer>`.

Note that, for the overload you actually want, the `observe` parameter is optional, so you can just do:

```js
return this.httpClient.post(this.uri, {}, { responseType: 'text' });
```

Also I got a much more helpful error when I actually tried to build with the broken service than I did inline in the IDE; it actually told me none of the overloads applied:

```
ERROR in src/app/service.ts:11:45 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 15, '(url: string, body: any, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.
  Overload 2 of 15, '(url: string, body: any, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "response"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.
  Overload 3 of 15, '(url: string, body: any, options?: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.

11     return this.http.post<string>("", {}, { responseType: "text" });
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@angular/common/http/http.d.ts:2297:9
    2297         responseType?: 'json';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'responseType' which is declared here on type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'
  node_modules/@angular/common/http/http.d.ts:93m2413:9
    2413         responseType?: 'json';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'responseType' which is declared here on type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "response"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'
  node_modules/@angular/common/http/http.d.ts:2458:9
    2458         responseType?: 'json';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'responseType' which is declared here on type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got a service which wraps the `HttpClient` but trying to set `responseType` doesn't work, the only way that I can get the error to go away is by doing `responseType: 'text' as 'json'`

> responseType: 'text' as 'json'